# QT There are no errors or warnings but it doesn't output anything

Tags: c++, qt

My code is supposed to find all the Amicable numbers in between 2 numbers (a and b).
I have tried other compilers and it worked but I need GUI.
Here's the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTextStream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int a, b, c, l;
    string data_1, temp;
    QString data;
    QString A = ui->frst->text();
    QString L = ui->lst->text();
    a = A.toInt();
    l = L.toInt();
    for (int k = a; k <= l; k++) {
        int s1 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a / 2; i++) {
            if (a % i == 0)
                s1 = s1 + i;
        }
        b = s1;
        int s2 = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= b / 2; i++) {
            if (b % i == 0)
                s2 = s2 + i;
        }
        c = s2;
        if (a == c && c != b && a <= l && b <= l) {
            temp = to_string(b) + " and " + to_string(c) + "... \r\n";
            data_1 += temp;
        }
    }
    data = QString::fromStdString(data_1);
    ui->OutPut->setText(data);
}
```

where:
frst is the a input,
lst is the b input(both are EditLines),
and OutPut is Label to show the found numbers

Comment: Have you created the project using Qt Creator or manually?

Comment: What does "but it doesn't output anything" mean? Have you verified what you get in "a", "l" and "data_1"? Have you verified that it enters `if(a==c && c!=b && a<=l && b<=l){`?

Comment: @Filip using Qt Creator

Comment: ***I have tried other compilers and it worked*** I think you should show the code that worked. I don't think the problem here is the Qt code. I think there is a flaw in your algorithm. If it worked before somehow you messed up that part when converting to use Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works however maybe you are not giving the right input, I have tried your code in Qt it works as it should, try to input 220 and 284, this will find the amicable numbers between that range.

Here is the output I got:

[image]

Comment: Yes,but if I input 1 and 300 there are no numbers, but 220 and 284 are in this range

Comment: Yes but I don't think you understand your code completely, your code will only check if 2 inputted numbers are amicable, not find every 2 amicable numbers in the range.

Comment: I agree, the problem must have occurred between the code that works and the code that is presented in the question. Removing Qt from the code using only the algorithm returns no results for 1 and 300: [https://ideone.com/KKw81o](https://ideone.com/KKw81o)